# How to write java code using mongodb query builder to retrieve a document using "_id"?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

How to convert following query to java code using mongodb QueryBuilder?

```
db.event.find({"_id":ObjectId("55aff4883e688fbea60d0698")})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("_id").is(ObjectId("55aff4883e688fbea60d0698")).get();
```

Comment: Gives an Error "The method ObjectId(String) is undefined for the type QuerryTest"

Answer (score 0):

```
//set up DB

//select the collection
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("event");

//Retrieve
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(QueryBuilder.start().put("_id")
                    .is("55aff4883e688fbea60d0698").get());

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: What did you get in output? What version of mongodb and java are you using?

Comment: I got nothing as the output maybe due to "_id" type is ObjectId not a String. When I ask this question I was working with 2.0 and recently moved to 3.0 it seems more convenient with filters.

Comment: Okay, check that the object is in the DB. If you post your code, we could debug it faster.